# Swapping elements between A and B to get sums equality

Tags: python, algorithm

> We have two arrays of equal length, `A` and `B`. also, for every `i`: `0 <= a_i, b_i <= m` for some `1<=m<= 1000000`. We want to check if a single swap between some term of `A` and some term of `B` will make the sums of the arrays be equal.

Consider the following solution:

```
def fast_solution(A, B, m):
  n = len(A)
  sum_a = sum(A)
  sum_b = sum(B)
  d = sum_b - sum_a
  if d % 2 == 1:
    return False
  d //= 2
  count = counting(A, m) # returns a mapping <integer, #occurrences in A>
  for i in range(n):
    if 0 <= B[i] - d and B[i] - d <= m and count[B[i] - d] > 0:
      return True
  return False
```

I'd be glad if you could explain the reasoning behind the last `if` clause.

[Source of the problem](https://codility.com/media/train/2-CountingElements.pdf)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If there is such a swap, then the difference between the two values must be half that of the difference in the sums. Swapping two values means that the sum of *both* lists will change, one going up, the other down, by the same amount. The two changes *must* add up to the difference between the sums before the swap, and both sums change by the same value (`+d` and `-d`, or *value* delta, which is the difference between the two swapped values).

First, the function calculates `d` as a delta between the sums, the sum delta. Note that `sum_a` could be *larger* than `sum_b`, at which point the result `sum_b - sum_a` is negative. This simply means that there must be a value in `B` that is smaller than the target value in `A`, a swap then would decrease `sum_a` and increase `sum_b` to make them equal. If the parity of the sum delta is *odd* rather than even, you'll never find a value delta that is half the sum delta so the function returns `False` at this point. The final value of `d` is the *value* delta, the amount of difference between the two swapped values. Remember, the value delta is half the sum delta.

The algorithm counts all values in `A`, then tests all values in `B`. It would only be possible to swap two values between `A` and `B` if there is *a* value in `B` that differs by `d` from *a* value in `A`. The value in `A` to swap with `B` would need to be equal to `b_value - d`. For a negative `d` (`sum_a > sum_b`) that would make `b_value` smaller, for a positive `d` that would require `b_value` to be the bigger number.

The `if` test looks to see if there is a value in `B - d` available in `A`, but it first tests if `b_value - d` is still within the range of [0-m]:

- `0 <= B[i] - d` test if the number sought for in A is still a positive number.
- `B[i] - d <= m` tests  if the number sought is still no larger than `m`; it could be if `B[i]` was close and `d` is negative.
- `count` contains counts for the numbers in `A`; if `count[B[i] - d] > 0` is true, then there is at least one such number in A. This is a number that can be swapped.

The range test is needed because the `counted` list only holds counts for the numbers from 0 through to m (inclusive), not for negative numbers or for numbers larger than `m`.

The function can be improved by using a set instead of a counting function. There is no need to know how many times a number appears in `A`, just that it *exists*. This would make boundary checks obsolete, because numbers out of bound are simply not going to be present in a set of the values of `A`.

Once we have a set of values of A, we can test if this set is [disjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_sets) from the set of b values with the delta applied, using [`set.isdisjoint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.isdisjoint):

```
def faster_solution(A, B, m=None):  # m is ignored in this version
    delta = sum(A) - sum(B)
    if delta % 2 == 1:
        return False
    delta //= 2
    return not set(A).isdisjoint(b - delta for b in B)
```

This returns True if there is a value in `A` that is equal to *a* value in `B` minus the delta. Python will only loop over the `b - delta for b in B` loop until a match is found (at which point the sets are not disjoint, and `not` inverses that result to True), or the loop has been exhausted and so no such value is found in `A` and the sets are found to be disjoint.

The `counter()` function shown has another issue: it requires way more memory than is needed, and it is very slow compared to a [`collections.Counter()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) which has an optimised loop implemented in to do the counting. A `Counter()` uses a dictionary (hash map) to store counts only for counts greater than 0.

The set solution above beats the 'fast solution' hands down:

```
>>> import timeit, random
>>> m = 1000000
>>> testdata = [random.randrange(m + 1) for _ in range(1000)]
>>> testinputs = (testdata[:], testdata[:])
>>> random.shuffle(testinputs[0])  # The order of A differs from B
>>> testinputs[1][-1] -= testinputs[1][-1] // 2  # now the two sums differ by an even amount, guaranteed to be in range
>>> assert testinputs[1][-1] > 0  # make sure the original random value was not 0 or 1.
>>> # note: It's the *last value in B* that makes it possible to swap;
... # this is one of two worst-case scenarios (the other is even-delta-no-swap).
...
>>> assert fast_solution(*testinputs, m)    # the original finds a solution
>>> assert faster_solution(*testinputs, m)  # my version finds a solution
>>> timeit.timeit("f(*ab, m)", "from __main__ import fast_solution as f, testinputs as ab, m", number=1000)
2.3270092820748687
>>> timeit.timeit("f(*ab, m)", "from __main__ import faster_solution as f, testinputs as ab, m", number=1000)
0.13949943508487195
```

Not using a counter, and using Python's set functionality made that about 17 times faster for inputs of length 1000!

The moral of the story: use the best tools available in your language of choice, and think critically about what is actually needed to solve the problem. Python's built-in types and operations often can let you avoid running the critical loops in Python bytecode, significantly reducing the constant-time factors of an algorithm.

Comment: I'd upvote it 10 times if I could. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

From https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-pair-swapping-which-makes-sum-of-two-arrays-same:

> We are looking for two values, a and b, such that:

```
sumA - a + b = sumB - b + a
2b - 2a = sumB - sumA
b - a = (sumB - sumA) / 2
```

`(sumB - sumA) / 2` is a target difference `d`

`count[B[i] - d] > 0` - this simply means that there must exist such value in the array `A` in order to satisfy condition

Answer (score 2):

This for-loop at the end searches each element of the `B` array. To be the swapped element at index `i`, it has to satisfy two conditions:

- `B[i] - d` must be between `0` and `m`. You can imagine `2 * d` as how much `sum(B)` is larger than `sum(A)`, so by swapping `B[i]` with `B[i] - d`, array `A` with gain `d` and array `B` will lose it, increasing the difference by `2 * d`
- `B[i] - d` must exist in A

It's not good for understanding though to redefine `d = d / 2` in the middle of the code :)